# Restoring Catalog & Product Data

Tags: magento-1.7, mysql, database

We Have a problem where by a category was deleted and then recreated causing problems as the id changed, Is it possible to restore just the product tables as do not want to loose changes which have occured to other tables such as orders, customers etc.

Has Anyone restored all the catalog_ tables and did it work? Or is there something which might cause further problems?

Comment: I would not recommend restoring "some tables" you will most likely have problems in the future. Where are you having issues with the id? Did you delete the category from admin?

Comment: Do you have a database backup with you? If so create a new database and install the backup and re-install your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just restore the `catalog_*` tables from a dump. Just be sure, that you insert the `AUTOINCREMENT` values as well. But a standard dump does what you need.